# How to use --create-application=false with ng new command

Tags: angular-cli

My motive is to create a UI library of my own using Angular 9. I was going through the Angular official documentation about [Creating Libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries). They started with this command:

> ng new my-workspace --create-application=false

And they say that `--create-application=false` will instruct the CLI to create the config file only and not the application code. Out of curiosity I created 2 projects one with this parameter and other one I generated normally with `ng new my-project` just to see what is the difference between project structure. I'm confused to see both are same.

**Left one is without parameter while Right one is with parameter:**
[image]

Please correct my mistake.

My versions are:

> Angular CLI: 6.2.9

> Node: 10.19.0

> OS: linux x64

Here is a recording of my steps: https://youtu.be/wsedP3DAsl4

Comment: I think you are comparing the full project to itself. I just did the same thing you describe and the CLI produced exactly what is expected. 2 completely different results; one with the minimum files, one with all the scaffolded files for an angular application.

Comment: @R.Richards. this is strange. I again created one more workspace using `ng new --create-application=false` and again I can see all the files including `app component` and other application code. I'm adding my versions in the question.

Comment: @R.Richards, Can you please upload your project folder's screenshot somewhere. I want to tally few things. Please.

Comment: @R.Richards, Here i've uploaded a screen recording of my steps: https://youtu.be/wsedP3DAsl4

Comment: `--create-application` is not a valid option for that version of the CLI. Think about upgrading to the latest version. You could have found this out yourself by running `ng new --help` and see that option is not listed.

Comment: @R.Richards, Ok. I'll upgrade to latest and then I'll come back to you :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Angular CLI: 15.2.4, so, in order to work the command I used `ng new myApp --create-application=false` and works.

C:

Answer (score 3):

> The --create-application flag is used with the ng new command. Setting
> this to false tells ng new not to create the initial Angular
> application in the Workspace. By default this flag is set to true to
> match the behavior of the previous versions of Angular CLI.

More info at this Medium blog post: [Angular In Depth](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-workspace-no-application-for-you-4b451afcc2ba#:%7E:text=The%20%2D%2Dcreate%2Dapplication%20flag%20is%20used%20with%20the%20ng,previous%20versions%20of%20Angular%20CLI.)

So the difference is that you can create multiple 'projects' that share the same workspace instead of having one workspace for each project that would mean having one node_modules folder and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Look I had this error `Error: Unknown argument: createApplication` then what I do is use sudo like this `sudo ng new my-workspace --createapplication=false` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

maybe resolve your problem:

- ng new my-workspace --skip-install
- Remove ./src
- ng generate application [name] --style=[name] --routing=[boolean]